# Resttemplate postForEntity with null body

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, resttemplate

I want to make a Post request with resttemplate, but the body shall be null.

```
 ResponseEntity<myObject> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(getBaseUrl(), null , myObject.class);
```

When I do this I get

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 : [{"timestamp":"2021-06-30T12:36:29.760+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/api/v1"}]
> at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:133)
> at

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1")
public class ApiController {

    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
    public ExecutionMetaData execute(@RequestBody(required = false) @Nullable ParameterDTO ParameterDTO)  
    {
       doSomeThing();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @user7294900 this is not exactly the same question! You have to pass a header indicating the content type if you pass null in the body.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli You can add header without body as in duplicate answers

Comment: @user7294900 sure that's what I say. But the duplicate post doesn't directly answer this question! You shouldn't delete a question that is no 100% a duplicate!

Comment: Create one http header and set content type as application/json. Then create a httpEntity set the header and set null body. new HttpEntity<>(null, header), add this restTemplate call instead null.